# Why do pygettext translates strings in tuples but not strings in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, translation, gettext

I used pygettext to translate a python module, and it created the po file correctly, but when it comes to translating, it does not translate everything.
For example:

```
txt=(_("Wait"),_("shutting"),_("down..."))
```

The strings in the tuple get translated correctly

```
Menu_Main = [
    (_("Begin Exam"), "test(duration=env['TEST_DURATION'])"),
    (_("Back to Parameters Monitor"), "menu_return(True)"),
]
```

The strings in this tuples list don't get translated. Why?

I installed the language this way:

```
lang = "it"
gettext.textdomain('domain')
gettext.bindtextdomain('domain', '/usr/share/locale')
la = gettext.translation('domain', '/usr/share/locale',languages=lang.split(),fallback=True)
_ = la.gettext
la.install(names=['gettext'])
```

I tried to use xgettext instead of pygettext but nothing changed

Comment: Are the strings localised in the .mo file…?

Comment: yes, msgfmt compiles correctly and all the strings are present in the mo, but some of them don't get translated

Comment: Does `print(_("Begin Exam"))` outside the list work…? There should really be no difference between putting this inside a list expression and outside it…

Comment: yes, i tried it in the python console and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution to the problem. I had the tuples nested in a list, and a menu which was iterating over them, so i had to use defferred translations.
Inside the for loop:

```
draw.text((dt_x, dt_y) , _(mytext), font=myfont, fill="white")
```

I had to wrap mytext (the tuple of strings) with the _() function.